# How does the Haskell compiler "know" that IO cannot be unwrapped?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, type-constructor

Obviously, the following function is impossible, because it is impossible to unwrap an IO value permanently (ignoring unsafePerformIO or similar):

```
unwrapIO :: IO String -> String
unwrapIO (IO str) = str
```

However, similar functions such as the following are possible:

```
unwrapJust :: Maybe String -> String
unwrapJust (Just str) = str
unwrapJust Nothing = "ignore this plz"
```

I fully understand the reasoning behind why #2 is possible but #1 is not, but I do not understand how. Can I also make my own types that are not unwrappable?

Comment: `IO` is a primitive and has no constructors, so cannot be unwrapped.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Just` and `Nothing` are data constructors for the type `Maybe a`. `IO` has no data constructors to speak of (in GHC it actually has constructors but they're really implementation details of GHC, and other implementations might define `IO` differently).

`unwrapIO (IO str) = str` doesn't make sense in the same way `unwrapMaybe (Maybe str) = str` doesn't make sense. `IO` and `Maybe` are not data constructors, so you cannot pattern-match on them.

Answer (score 9):

It's because the data constructor of `IO` is not exported. I mean, you can think it's not exported.

You can prevent your own type from being unwrapped by using the same strategy.

```
module Test (Test, test) where

data Test a = MkTest a

test :: a -> Test a
test = MkTest
```

You can create a value of `Test` using `test`, but you cannot unwrap it using pattern-match because `MkTest` is not exported.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that while the existing answers are mostly true, there is a deeper reason why `IO` can not be unwrapped. [Conceptually](https://wiki.haskell.org/IO_inside), `type IO a = RealWorld -> (a, RealWorld)`. `IO` is a function type (in real implementations hidden behind a newtype wrapper or equivalent machinery).

So, how would you go about unwrapping a function? Easy, you just call it!. But how are you going to get an instance of `RealWorld`? That is the truer primitive: you can not construct a `RealWorld`, there is only ever one.

The monadic instance of course can just pass `RealWorld` as a state, kind of like `StateT` and in the end, the only instance ever constructed is at startup of the program, then it is passed down between the `IO`s.

Coming back to reality again, this is (again) a lie. You actually can get hold of an instance of `RealWorld` and you can call an `IO a` action "ahead of time". There is a function that does exactly what you asked for. It is called [`System.IO.Unsafe.unsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.2/base-4.12.0.0/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO) though it is in an unsafe package for a reason.